# android RadioButton button drawable gravity

Tags: android, radio-button, center, drawable

I am generating RadioButtons dynamically with

```
RadioButton radioButton=new RadioButton(context);  

LayoutParams layoutParams=new LayoutParams(radioWidth,radioHeight);
layoutParams.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;

radioButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

BitmapDrawable bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawableResource);
bitmap.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

radioButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.itabs_radio));
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(bitmap);
```

as you can see I am desperately trying to set gravity of button drawable to center, but without a reason its always center and left aligned, heres the reason- the default style of android radio button:

```
<style name="Widget.CompoundButton">
<item name="android:focusable">true</item> 
<item name="android:clickable">true</item>
<item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearance</item> 
<item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryDisableOnly</item> 
<item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|left</item> 
</style>

<style name="Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
<item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_radio_label_background</item> 
<item name="android:button">@android:drawable/btn_radio</item> 
</style>
```

**Is there any way I can align button drawable to center?**

Answer (score 68, accepted):

According to [`CompoundButton.onDraw()` source code](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/CompoundButton.java&q=android%20RadioButton&d=4&l=229) it's always left-aligned.

(Note the line `buttonDrawable.setBounds(0, y, buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), y + height);`)

You will have to derive a new class from `RadioButton` and override `onDraw()`.

**EXAMPLE ADDED LATER:**

Ok, so here's what you do. Firstly, here's a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<org.test.TestProj.RadioButtonCenter
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="100dp" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Button test"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Secondly here's the custom-drawing RadioButtonCenter:

```
package org.test.TestProj;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class RadioButtonCenter extends RadioButton {

    public RadioButtonCenter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CompoundButton, 0, 0);
        buttonDrawable = a.getDrawable(1);
        setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
    }
    Drawable buttonDrawable;


     @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            if (buttonDrawable != null) {
                buttonDrawable.setState(getDrawableState());
                final int verticalGravity = getGravity() & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
                final int height = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

                int y = 0;

                switch (verticalGravity) {
                    case Gravity.BOTTOM:
                        y = getHeight() - height;
                        break;
                    case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
                        y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
                        break;
                }

            int buttonWidth = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int buttonLeft = (getWidth() - buttonWidth) / 2;
            buttonDrawable.setBounds(buttonLeft, y, buttonLeft+buttonWidth, y + height);
                buttonDrawable.draw(canvas);
            }
        }   
}
```

Finally, here's an **attrs.xml** file you need to put in **res/values** so the code can get at platform-defined attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
     <declare-styleable name="CompoundButton">
        <attr name="android:button" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample snippet ? I'm not able to figure it out!

Comment: Yes its really worth of 1000s. But I am not accepting it since I approached it with according to me a simpler way. No disrespect. Thanx again!

Comment: Thanks a bunch Shardul. Allow me to point out that your version has a custom constructor, does not use attributes properly, and therefore cannot be used as a drop-in replacement for RadioButton. Never mind. That's the last time I ever go to that kind of trouble.

Comment: Also, allow me to point out that I *did* answer your question: you subclass RadioButton.

Comment: instead of android.R.id.empty , define transparent color and use R.color.transparent instead, otherwise,InflateException get thrown but the real cause of it is `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from drawable resource ID #0x1020004`

Comment: Thanks Theo, but what do you mean by "define transparent color"??

Comment: `setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);`

Comment: Hi @ReubenScratton , i tried your solution , but i am getting error 
com.packagename.RadioButtonCenter  fail to instantiate , may I know what is left ?

Comment: @ReubenScratton how to change the images ?

Comment: is there any way to get drawable and text both centre aligned of radio button? please check here http://stackoverflow.com/q/26710100/2624806

Comment: I did find that in newer Targets, the call to super.onDraw() actually causes issues, and draws the image left justified, before your ondraw executes... this did not happen in lower targets, but started in higher targets, so food for thought.

Comment: Excellent answer and in fact the only solution for this problem that works properly. It is a damn shame that you have to do things like this for such a simple task, though.

Comment: When using `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'` `a.getDrawable(1);` returns null. Using `a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CompoundButton_android_button);` works for me though.

Comment: When I set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on the button the button image is croped.

Comment: @ReubenScratton,  
how to use it to align text and left drawable to right of radiobutton

Comment: on android 7.0. It not highlight when choose tab diff.

Comment: I have filled a bug report with the solution https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/125138960 If you think this will be fixed, push google to fix it, thx

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution, you can add a background to RadioButton, or set background="@null", .

```
<RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/cp_rd_btn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"/>
```

updated:

```
<RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/account_coolme_selector"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/account_qq_selector"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
            </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: this doesn't resolve the problem - the button of the radio will still be aligned to the left

Comment: hoot, thanks for the effort - but still no. The task is to align the `button` object, you are using drawableTop. See the accepted answer - you need to implement a custom RadioButton to achieve this.

Comment: Good, it's definitely an hack but it works. I had to have a radio button only with an image no text and the image needed to be centered. I just made textsize = 0 and got exactly what I needed +1

Answer (score 3):

Based on @hoot answers, I had customised it to make both text and drawable to the center without using attars,

```
class RadioButtonCenter(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : RadioButton(context, attrs) {
internal var buttonDrawable: Drawable? = null


init {
    buttonDrawable = CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(this@RadioButtonCenter)

}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val iconHeight = buttonDrawable!!.intrinsicHeight
    val buttonWidth = buttonDrawable!!.intrinsicWidth

    val totalWidth =
        buttonWidth + paint.measureText(text.toString()) + paddingLeft + paddingRight + compoundDrawablePadding
    if (totalWidth >= width) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    } else {
        setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent)

        val availableSpace = ((width - totalWidth) / 2).toInt()

        buttonDrawable!!.state = drawableState
        val height = height
        var yTop = 0
        val verticalGravity = gravity and Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK
        when (verticalGravity) {
            Gravity.BOTTOM -> yTop = height - iconHeight
            Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL -> yTop = (height - iconHeight) / 2
        }
        var rightWidth = availableSpace + buttonWidth

        buttonDrawable!!.setBounds(availableSpace, yTop, rightWidth, yTop + iconHeight)
        buttonDrawable!!.draw(canvas)

        rightWidth += compoundDrawablePadding

        val yPos = (height / 2 - (paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2) as Float
        canvas.drawText(
            text.toString(),
            (rightWidth).toFloat(),
            yPos,
            paint
        )
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Reprator answers.

**JAVA version:**

```
public class RadioButtonCentered extends AppCompatRadioButton {

  private Drawable buttonDrawable;


  public RadioButtonCentered(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public RadioButtonCentered(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public RadioButtonCentered(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }




  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      if (buttonDrawable != null) {
        int iconHeight = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int buttonWidth = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int width = getWidth();
        float totalWidth = buttonWidth + getPaint().measureText(getText().toString()) + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getCompoundDrawablePadding();

        if (totalWidth >= width) { super.onDraw(canvas); }
        else {
            int yTop = 0;
            int height = getHeight();
            int availableSpace = (int) ((width - totalWidth) / 2);
            int verticalGravity = getGravity() & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
            int rightWidth = availableSpace + buttonWidth;

            switch (verticalGravity) {
                case Gravity.BOTTOM:
                    yTop = height - iconHeight;
                    break;
                case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
                    yTop = (height - iconHeight) / 2;
                    break;
            }

            setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
            buttonDrawable.setState(getDrawableState());
            buttonDrawable.setBounds(availableSpace, yTop, rightWidth, yTop + iconHeight);
            buttonDrawable.draw(canvas);

            float yPos = (height / 2 - (getPaint().descent() + getPaint().ascent()) / 2);

            canvas.drawText(getText().toString(), ((float) (rightWidth + getCompoundDrawablePadding())), yPos, getPaint());
        }
    } else {buttonDrawable = CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(this); invalidate();}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also think this sounds like a bug since it's always left-aligned. In my case I solved the issue by setting `android:minWidth="0dp"` and `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, since Material components had set the `android:minWidth` to a width larger than the drawable width. If the `RadioButton` needs to be centered it can then be added to a container and thus no custom view needs to be implemented.

Here's an example of how it could look:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:minWidth="0dp" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

However, be aware that the minimum width was set there for a reason, Material design used `?attr/minTouchTargetSize`. So if you do like above, the container should maybe also be touchable.

Answer (score 0):

`<radiogroup android:paddingLeft = "20dp" android:background="@color/gray">`

Basically - I have a horizontally aligned radio group, and by expanding the background color to the left 20dp (or whatever 1/2 of your width of radio button) it appears as if it's centered.

Answer (score 0):

you need foreground. not background. see args for layout and set em programmatically:

```
<RadioButton>
    ...
    android:button="@null"
    android:foreground="@drawable/your_selector_for_center_drawable"
    android:background="@drawable/your_selector_for_background_drawable"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
</RadioButton>
```