# How to center RadioButton graphic in a wide RadioButton widget in Android?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have a RadioGroup with four radio buttons, I have them using weightsum of 4 to evenly space them on the screen. This works great but what the result is the graphic is aligned left not in the center of each radio button. Is there a way to move the graphic to the center? I tried gravity center but this had no effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that they are always left-aligned for the default widget. However, you can do it with a custom one, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407553/android-radiobutton-button-drawable-gravity).

Comment: Geeze, I have to say that is way more of a pain in the ass then it should be. But this worked perfect thanks a lot.