# RadioButton center drawable / layout flattening

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-radiobutton

I have to do some flattening on my layout, below piece of it after. Percent `TextView` and `RadioButton` are in same place on the left and are switching using animations. Second `TextView` shows some text fulfilling width. Problem is that `RadioButton` is shorter than percent `TextView`, but I'm using `alignLeft` and `alignRight` for same width, and even with gravity set to `center` radio drawable is aligned left. I've found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407553/android-radiobutton-button-drawable-gravity), but is a bit old, before Material, and currently this class is more complicated. Any advice how to center this radio in own width (or width of percent textview) without! adding another `ViewGroup`? (precent and radio might be in another `RelativeLayout` and set `centerInParent`, as I had before tries for flattening)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option_percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ems="3"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/option_percent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/option_percent"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/option_percent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried using marginLeft in the radiobutton?

Comment: no, because it's not centering `RadioButton`, only moving. radio Drawables have different width on different devices. For now my only idea is to programmatically measure percent `TextView` and set properly calculated `marginLeft` for `RadioButton`, looking for easier way, maybe xml-only. Anyway thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have some workaround for my case. I'm not accepting this post, because its not a proper answer. Im still counting on another way, more elegant ;)

from above xml I've set fixed width for percent and removed ems, practically no difference. also removed aligning left and right to percent in radio attributes, so it have own size in both dimensions (`wrap_content`). next step is in code:

```
if(radioMarginLeft<0) {
    int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    percentTextView.getLayoutParams().width, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    radioButton.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    radioMarginLeft = (percentTextView.getLayoutParams().width -
                    radioButton.getMeasuredWidth())/2;
}

((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) radioButton.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin=radioMarginLeft;
```

measuring radio, percent now has fixed width, so no need to measure.  `radioMarginLeft` is calculated only once and kept outside method, in my case it may be even static.

additional: be careful with setting padding for radio, because of [Add margin between a RadioButton and its label in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134591/add-margin-between-a-radiobutton-and-its-label-in-android) (check most upvoted answer)